# Getting error while installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed node through `brew install node`, Node has been installed but after running:

`npm install -g create-react-native-app`

`npm` is showing the following error:

```
module.js:487

   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
```

Comment: What command did you run to get it to show that error?

Comment: I run 'npm install -g create-react-native-app' and got this error.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing yarn.

`brew install yarn`

`yarn global add npm`

`npm --version`

Hope that works.

Comment: Alternatively, uninstalling node/npm then reinstalling it seems to also work.